# Is there any way for log4j appender to output what category called it?

Tags: java, log4j, kibana

I have a very standard log4j config file.  I have 30+ categories,  and they all basically go to STDOUT.  (catalina.out)

catalina.out is then loaded into Kibana.

I need a way to filter by category,  so I need something to key off of.  Is there any way to set a variable, something to send to the appender to log what category the log entry came from?

I do NOT want to do a 1 to 1 ratio of category to appender.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%c` in a pattern layout (or enhanced pattern layout) to output the category https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: Of course.  But if I want to group them together in some way...  I don't want to move the package names of the classes,  but someway to add a variable from the category to the appender.